# I am trying to run a jenkins pipeline with gradle+sonarqube, need help due to error message

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube

I need help figuring out why my pipeline won't work. I already figured out how to get jenkins with my github. All I need to do now is get it where I can see the code to show up on sonarqube for analysis. I am using gradle not maven, and most tutorials show good examples for maven...

Here is my code:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages{

    stage('SonarQube analysis') {
        steps{
                withSonarQubeEnv(installationName: 'Sonar9.5', credentialsId: 'sonarqube-token') {
                 sh './gradlew sonarqube \
                 -Dsonar.projectKey=${#key} \
                 -Dsonar.host.url=${"#url"} \
                 -Dsonar.login=${#auth} \
                 -Dsonar.projectName=${#name} \
                 -Dsonar.projectVersion=${"not provided"}'
                }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Hope that's not your real key. Remove from post and rotate it!

Comment: the error message suggest you are running on windows, have you tried the `bat` step instead?